# Modificar estado dentro de un array de objetos

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

tengo una duda sobre el código que estoy haciendo. Resulta que en el estado inicial tengo un array de objetos y quiero modificar dentro de ellos la propiedad dinamicInput que es de tipo array para que me añada más objetos dentro de la misma. He llegado a 2 modos de resolverlo, la primera funciona, pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo con la segunda (me modifica el valor que quiero, pero a la vez me está añadiendo valores al final del array que no quiero) me despejaría varias dudas de cómo manejar el estado de esa manera. Dejo el código

https://codesandbox.io/s/still-hooks-nuwrqe?file=/src/App.js:23-1363

No funciona bien en codesandbox ni idea porque, pero bueno.

Esto me devuelve el estado si lo hago de la segunda manera (imagen) Lo del cuadro rojo no lo quiero :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo hacerlo de la 2da forma se lo agradecería. Un saludo

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas para insertar el código en la pregunta misma. Parte esencial de la pregunta se perderá si el enlace llega a romperse. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Por cierto, el código, los mensajes de error y la salida en consola siempre _como texto, con formato_.

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que quieres hacer, si me explicas más a detalle te puedo ayudar

Comment: @Ivandez Gracias por responder. Si ves el código que dejé en codesandbox (linea 17) Tengo el "método 1" que me agrega un objeto a la propiedad dinamicInput del primer objetos del estado. Hasta ahí todo funciona bien. Lo que quiero saber es que si se puede hacer la misma funcionalidad con el "método 2" (linea 25). Ya que se podría hacer en una sola linea y sin crear 2 constantes como en el método 1.